# Reputation change in the notification bar appears to be incorrect

Tags: bug, reputation, globalinbox

We get notification for reputation changes like below.

[image]

The problem is, it shows +1? When I open the link, it shows me +10.

Assuming this was to save space or indicate how many updates/changes had occurred  I downvoted some one and it updated to +9

This is now confusing... if it was +1 to represent 10 points (or 1 change/update/notifications), then +9 should mean 90 (or 9 changes)?

(Please note, I've removed the down vote)

Is this the expected behaviour? It has been going on for a few weeks I think.

Comment: I noticed the same since some days. Maybe it shows up when a downvoted question got deleted. Like a refund of your -1.

Comment: @nixda, I don't *think* so because when I click on it, it shows me +10... It seems like it's a bug